# Jaccard coefficient of adjacent vertices in igraph R

Tags: r, igraph

It is well known that the Jaccard similarity coefficient of two vertices is the number of common neighbors divided by the number of vertices that are neighbors of at least one of the two vertices under question. In Igraph R there is the function similarity.jaccard() which compute the above-defined coefficient for arbitrary vertices in a graph. I want to compute only the Jaccard coefficients for adjacent vertices (i.e., the so-called Jaccard coeffcient of an edge) and I want to obtain my results in the form of vector of the length equal to the numer of edges of the considered graph. I found the solution of such problem for Igraph C library with which I am not familiar. I want to obtain such results in Igraph R. How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a function to compute the jaccard similarity for the ends of a single edge and applying it to all edges.  Since you do not provide any data, I will illustrate with an arbitrary graph.

**Arbitrary Example Graph**

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1234)
g = erdos.renyi.game(10,0.3)
plot(g)
```

[image: Example graph]

Now apply a jaccard similarity function to all edges

```
sapply(E(g),  
    function(x) similarity.jaccard(g, as.vector(ends(g,x)))[1,2])
 [1] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.4000000 0.1666667 0.2000000 0.2000000
 [8] 0.2500000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

You can test some data points. For example,  the 7th edge goes between vertices 2 and 8 and the jaccard similarity is 0.2

```
E(g)[7]
+ 1/13 edge:
[1] 2--8
similarity.jaccard(g, c(2,8))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1.0  0.2
[2,]  0.2  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your aswer. This solution works very well for my graphs.